# Find the limit to $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^5+y^2}{x^4+|y|}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

My problem is evaluating the following limit:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^5+y^2}{x^4+|y|}$$
The answer should be 0. I tried to convert the limit into polar form, but it didn't help because I couldn't isolate the $r$ and $\theta$-variables of the expression. My "toolbox" for solving problems like these is very limited... If polar form doesn't work, then I usually have no clue on how to continue.

**Edit**: I think this is the solution. 
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\left|\frac{x^5+y^2}{x^4+|y|}\right| = \frac{|x^5+y^2|}{|x^4+|y||}
$$
Applying the triangle inequality gives
$$
\frac{|x^5+y^2|}{|x^4+|y||} \leq \left|\frac{x^5}{x^4+|y|}\right| + \left|\frac{y^2}{x^4+|y|}\right|
$$
Inspecting the denominators on the RHS gives:
$$
\left|\frac{x^5}{x^4+|y|}\right| \leq |x|, \quad\left|\frac{y^2}{x^4+|y|}\right| \leq |y|
$$
So
$$
\left|\frac{x^5}{x^4+|y|}\right| + \left|\frac{y^2}{x^4+|y|}\right| \leq |x| + |y|
$$
Since $|x| + |y| \to 0$ when $x,y\to 0$, the sandwich theorem states that $|\frac{x^5+y^2}{x^4+|y|}| \to 0$. And if $\lim |f(x)|=0$ then $\lim f(x)=0$ which solves the original problem.

Comment: No `\displaystyle` in titles please.

Comment: And now you are absolutely deadly completely sure the answer you newly accepted is correct, right? You checked it in depth, yes? Good.

Comment: As well as I could! But I thought the other answer was correct too, so who knows.

Comment: Scary. $ $ $ $ $ $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:)**

For paths $x=0$ as $y\to0$ and $y=0$ as $x\to0$ the result of limit clearly is zero, furthermore
$$\Big|\frac{x^5+y^2}{x^4+|y|}\Big|\leq\Big|\frac{x^5}{x^4+|y|}\Big|+\Big|\frac{y^2}{x^4+|y|}\Big|\leq|x|+|y|$$

Comment: Aha.. So you have used the triangle inequality to conclude that the absolute value of my limit is $\leq |x| + |y|$ which is $\to 0$ when $(x,y) \to (0,0)$? But don't you also need to show what the lower bound is 0 to apply the squeeze theorem?

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist $|x|+|y|<2\varepsilon$.

Comment: I read somewhere else that $\lim|f(x)| = 0 \implies \lim f(x) = 0$ is that what you mean?

Comment: Use limit definition $\epsilon-\delta$ form or squeeze theorem.  Study more!

Answer (score 0):

$0\le |\dfrac{x^5+y^2}{x^4 +|y|}| \le$

$\dfrac{|x^5| +|y^2|}{|x^4+|y||} \le$

$\dfrac{|x^5|}{x^4} + \dfrac{y^2}{|y|} =$

$|x| + |y|.$

And now?

Answer (score -1):

A common tool is to homogenise the denominator by setting $\displaystyle u=\frac{y}{x^4}$, then discuss the limit in function of $u$.

$\displaystyle f(x,y)=\frac{x^5+y^2}{x^4+|y|}=\frac{x^5+u^2x^8}{x^4+|u|x^4}=\frac{x+u^2x^4}{1+|u|}=\frac{x+uy}{1+|u|}=x\left(\frac 1{1+|u|}\right)+y\left(\frac u{1+|u|}\right)$

Since both $\frac 1{1+|u|}$ and $\frac u{1+|u|}$ are bounded (by $1$ in absolute value)

Then $|f(x,y)|\le |x|+|y|\to 0$

Comment: Does not work either, sorry.

Comment: To begin with, there are functions that are neither bounded nor going to infinity hence you are not exhausting all the cases.

Comment: ?? (Yes.) $ $ $ $

Comment: @Did do you like it better ?

Comment: The corrected version (which does not use homogenization at all) works, yes. By the way, this new version is what @MyGlasses wrote earlier.